# PHP Autoloading in Namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload, spl-autoload-register

I have had a slight problem with autoloading in my namespace. As shown on the PHP manual here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php you should be able to autoload namespace functions with a full qualified name e.g. \glue\common\is_email().

Thing is I have a function spl_autoload_register(array($import, "load")); within the initial namespace but whenever I try and call \glue\common\is_email() from the initial namespace it will not pass that autoload function but when using new is_email() (in the context of a class) it will. I don't get it the manual says I can autoload from fully qualified names but I can't :.

Here's my code:

```
namespace glue;

require_once 'import.php';

use glue\import as import;
use glue\core\router as router;

$import = new import();

spl_autoload_register(array($import, "load"));

/** Works and echos glue\router **/
$router = new router();

/** Don't do nothing **/
$cheese = \glue\common\is_email($email);
```

I also tried this code as well:

```
namespace glue;

require_once 'import.php';

use glue\import as import;
use glue\core\router as router;
use glue\common;

$import = new import();

spl_autoload_register(array($import, "load"));

/** Works and echos glue\router **/
$router = new router();

/** Don't do nothing **/
$cheese = common\is_email($email);
```

and finally this code:

```
namespace glue;

require_once 'import.php';

use glue\import as import;
use glue\core\router as router;
use glue\common\is_email as F;

$import = new import();

spl_autoload_register(array($import, "load"));

/** Works and echos glue\router **/
$router = new router();

/** Don't do nothing **/
$cheese = F($email);
```

Comment: Retagged as php5.3 as this is a 5.3-only question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's the only right answer.

**Every namespace needs its own spl_autoload_register() function.**

also, **spl_autoload_register() syntax *changed* in 5.3:**

```
spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ . "\\className::functionName"));
```

The following should work:

```
namespace glue;

require_once 'import.php';

use glue\import as import;
use glue\core\router as router;

$import = new import();

spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ . "\\$import::load"));

/** Works and echos glue\router **/
$router = new router();

/** Don't do nothing **/
$cheese = \glue\common\is_email($email);
```

---

Here is some **live** code that Just works!

in ../WebPageConsolidator.inc.php:

```
class WebPageConsolidator
{
    public function __construct() { echo "PHP 5.2 constructor.\n"; }
}
```

in test.php:

```
<?php

namespace WebPage;

class MyAutoloader
{
    public static function load($className)
    {
        require '../' . __NAMESPACE__ . $className . '.inc.php';
    }
}

spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ . "\\MyAutoloader::load");

class Consolidator extends \WebpageConsolidator
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "PHP 5.3 constructor.\n";

        parent::__construct();
    }
}

// Output: 
// PHP 5.3 constructor.
// PHP 5.2 constructor.
```

So I know it works.

Comment: Seemed like it could work but it still won't load my function. I'm starting to think PHP still overrides this functionality with it's runtime binding...which would kinda suck.

Comment: Yea it only goes into spl_autoload when using the new keyword........grrr why does PHP manual say I can autoload functions if I can't, might have to take this to them.

Comment: Yea as I still thought, dammit being able to load functions dependant on resolution of namespace to directory structure would be well good. I might suggest it to them, thanks for your help :).

Answer (score 1):

The misconception in the question of the OP is probably that functions/methods would be subject to autoloading – which they are not. Autoloading is only triggered by referencing classes.

This being said there still remains the **question about autoloading classes in namespaces**:

As of 2017 the current [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/) standard for autoloading is PSR-4 which provides the following autoloader code for namespaced classes:

```
<?php
/**
 * An example of a project-specific implementation.
 *
 * After registering this autoload function with SPL, the following line
 * would cause the function to attempt to load the \Foo\Bar\Baz\Qux class
 * from /path/to/project/src/Baz/Qux.php:
 *
 *      new \Foo\Bar\Baz\Qux;
 *
 * @param string $class The fully-qualified class name.
 * @return void
 */
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {

    // project-specific namespace prefix
    $prefix = 'Foo\\Bar\\';

    // base directory for the namespace prefix
    $base_dir = __DIR__ . '/src/';

    // does the class use the namespace prefix?
    $len = strlen($prefix);
    if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
        // no, move to the next registered autoloader
        return;
    }

    // get the relative class name
    $relative_class = substr($class, $len);

    // replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
    // separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
    // with .php
    $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';

    // if the file exists, require it
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
    }
});
```

The full spec text can be found at [PSR-4: Autoloader](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

The code example above (and another one to autoload from *multiple* namespaces) can be found at [Example Implementations of PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/) (or GitHub: [fig-standards/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md)).

Comment: Actually now PHP7 does allow autoloading of functions and methods in namespaces directly

Comment: Hi @Sammaye, thanks for the hint. Do you have some link with more information at hand? I can't seem to find anything about that change.

Comment: I don't know where @Sammaye got that from. Tried in 7.2.28 and does not work. Autoloading gets triggered by classes only. I already knew that, and it is in the PHP docs, but evidence beats ipse dixit =)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) to autoload your PHP Classes.

Check out how to do it in my recent blog post: https://enchanterio.github.io/enterprise-level-php/2017/12/25/the-magic-behind-autoloading-php-files-using-composer.html

Comment: The reason why this would work now is because php now allows autoloading of namespace functions

Comment: Sure. 7 years later many things have changed haha. I wanted to put here a reference to the new way of doing it as I landed in this question myself from Google.

Comment: Link https://enterprise-level-php.com/2017/12/25/the-magic-behind-autoloading-php-files-using-composer.html is broken

Comment: @boctulus thx for letting me know. I suspended the website few weeks ago, I just deployed to github pages at least so you can check out the article, link in the answer updated.