# Loading of php classes

Tags: java, php, classloader, php-5.3

How are classes loaded in php? Are they loaded each time a GET/POST is received. Or is it rather like tomcat in java where we have a persistent context listener. Where all classes are loaded upon initialization.

Secondly, are classes destroyed after they are used.

Im a exprience java programmer who is new to php.

Thanks

Comment: PHP dont't have anything like JVM, Php classes are not converted to byte code unlike JAVA. Whenever a request comes the class code is executed line by line by the interpreter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Way To Autoload Classes In PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806301/best-way-to-autoload-classes-in-php)