# automatic include mechanism in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way I can include **files same folder** ***automatically***?

I see lot of code in application I am working on that has this kind of code. Specific example is swift mailer (if anyone is aware of that). But this can also be used as general example:

```
 Folder: vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport

 |
 --- File MailInvoker.php
                 |
                 --- interface Swift_Transport_MailInvoker
 |
 --- File SimpleMailInvoker.php
                 |
                 --- class Swift_Transport_SimpleMailInvoker implements Swift_Transport_MailInvoker
```

I am unable to figure out without any specific include statements or without any mention in any of autoload files, how class can use interface.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Is this in a framework project? With that folder structure, I assume it's probably using the composer autoloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load classes automatic. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php for the offical documentation.

Basically you create a function to load classes and register it with `spl_autoload_register('autoloader_function_name');`
That function will be executed when the class isn't already included.

You can find the swift autoloader in the file swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift.php as `public static function autoload($class)`

Here, on stackoverflow, there are a many examples too:  [Best Way To Autoload Classes In PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806301/best-way-to-autoload-classes-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Composer is the best tool to autoload files, all modern frameworks use composer. To autoload a folder files you should inialize autoloading system and then follow some standards in file naming. You can read [this tutorial](http://vegibit.com/composer-autoloading-tutorial/) for more information about composer