# I want read a function inside a class

Tags: php

I do not undersand what's append.  (php7.x)

> [Fri Apr 19 02:48:49.446162 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2750]
>   [client xxx.xxx.84.89:48694] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP
>   Fatal error:  Uncaught LogicException: Function
>   'Core\OM\CORE::autoload' not found (class 'Core\OM\CORE' not
>   found) in /var/www/xxxx/xxxx/web8/web/client/index.php:29\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 /var/www/xxxx/xxxx/web8/web/client/index.php(29):
>   spl_autoload_register('ClicShopping\\OM...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in
>   /var/www/xxxx/xxxx/web8/web/client/index.php on line 29'

index.php

```
define('BASE_DIR', __DIR__ . '/shop/includes/Core/');

require(BASE_DIR . 'OM/CORE.php');

spl_autoload_register('Core\OM\CORE::autoload');
```

It seems there is a problem with this function: `spl_autoload_register`

I tried different things, it always gives the same error.
Like,

```
spl_autoload_register(['\\Core\\OM\\CORE', 'autoload']);
spl_autoload_register('Core\OM\CORE::autoload')
```

Do you have a similar problem?

On `var_dump(is_file(BASE_DIR . 'OM/CORE.php'));` ==> `true`

I do not understand why it does not want to go at the autoload function and it creates this error. It's like `CORE.php` is not read and does not exist.

I tried to put a `var_dump('test')` and `exit` on the top of the file `CORE.php`, but there is no message.
About the log generated, it is the same as above.

The `chmod` is on 644.

I have no idea how to resolve this problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What namespace has `/shop/includes/Core/OM/CORE.php`?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806301/best-way-to-autoload-classes-in-php

Comment: @DamianDziaduch . My problem is on my local linux, I have no problem, everything works perfect, not on my server. I do not touch on Core.php . The name space is :   namespace Core\OM;

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to load something that dose not exist, please echo the  path: **DIR** . '/shop/includes/Core/ to the browser body, in this location you require
the OM/CORE.php so it's trying to get the CORE.php file that resides in:
  **__DIR__ . '/shop/includes/Core/OM/CORE.php**

the function autoload purpose is to include PHP class files, so in your website, when you want to initiate a class object, first you need to include the PHP class
file. what about if e have a lot of classes?

Many developers writing object-oriented applications create one PHP source file per class definition. One of the biggest annoyances is having to write a long list of needed includes at the beginning of each script (one for each class).

In PHP 5, this is no longer necessary. The spl_autoload_register() function registers any number of autoloaders, enabling for classes and interfaces to be automatically loaded if they are currently not defined. By registering autoloaders, PHP is given a last chance to load the class or interface before it fails with an error.